# Why can't use currentNode.left===null in the code?

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree

My teacher was building a BST with a remove function.

In this remove funtion,i can't get the point about the second situation

which is called right child which doesn't have a left child

In this judgement condition,my teacher's solution is

> //Option 2: Right child which doesnt have a left child
>           } else if (currentNode.right.left===null) {

but what i think is

> //Option 2: Right child which doesnt have a left child
>           } else if (currentNode.left===null) {

and my teacher said put currentNode.left===null in his code 
will see the difference.

What i use to test the difference is to remove 20 in the tree.

Even though i replace it,I still can't get the difference between each other.

Could someone explain the difference?

Here is my teacher's JS code:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value){
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor(){
    this.root = null;
  }
   insert(value){
     const newNode = new Node(value);
    if (this.root === null) {
      this.root = newNode;
    } else {
      let currentNode = this.root;
      while(true){
        if(value < currentNode.value){
          //Left
          if(!currentNode.left){
            currentNode.left = newNode;
            return this;
          }
           currentNode = currentNode.left;
          } else {
            //Right
          if(!currentNode.right){
            currentNode.right = newNode;
            return this;
           } 
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
          }
         }
       }
      }
      lookup(value){
       if (!this.root) {
          return false;
        }
      let currentNode = this.root;
         while(currentNode){
         if(value < currentNode.value){
         currentNode = currentNode.left;
       } else if(value > currentNode.value){
         currentNode = currentNode.right;
       } else if (currentNode.value === value) {
          return currentNode;
       }
       }
          return null
        }
     remove(value) {
       if (!this.root) {
           return false;
        }
     let currentNode = this.root;
     let parentNode = null;
      while(currentNode){
         if(value < currentNode.value){
         parentNode = currentNode;
         currentNode = currentNode.left;
       } else if(value > currentNode.value){
          parentNode = currentNode;
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
        } else if (currentNode.value === value) {
          //We have a match, get to work!
    
           //Option 1: No right child: 
           if (currentNode.right === null) {
              if (parentNode === null) {
                  this.root = currentNode.left;
            } else {
        
             //if parent > current value, make current left child a child of parent
             if(currentNode.value < parentNode.value) {
                  parentNode.left = currentNode.left;
        
              //if parent < current value, make left child a right child of parent
              } else if(currentNode.value > parentNode.value) {
                   parentNode.right = currentNode.left;
              }
              }
    
              //Option 2: Right child which doesnt have a left child
              } else if (currentNode.right.left === null) {
                      currentNode.right.left = currentNode.left;
                      if(parentNode === null) {
                      this.root = currentNode.right;
               } else {
        
                //if parent > current, make right child of the left the parent
                   if(currentNode.value < parentNode.value) {
                       parentNode.left = currentNode.right;
        
                //if parent < current, make right child a right child of the parent
                 } else if (currentNode.value > parentNode.value) {
                       parentNode.right = currentNode.right;
                 } 
                 }
    
                 //Option 3: Right child that has a left child
                 } else {

                   //find the Right child's left most child
                   let leftmost = currentNode.right.left;
                   let leftmostParent = currentNode.right;
                   while(leftmost.left !== null) {
                   leftmostParent = leftmost;
                   leftmost = leftmost.left;
                  }
      
                 //Parent's left subtree is now leftmost's right subtree
                  leftmostParent.left = leftmost.right;
                  leftmost.left = currentNode.left;
                  leftmost.right = currentNode.right;

                  if(parentNode === null) {
                        this.root = leftmost;
                  } else {
                  if(currentNode.value < parentNode.value) {
                       parentNode.left = leftmost;
                  } else if(currentNode.value > parentNode.value) {
                       parentNode.right = leftmost;
                   }
                }
              }
                   return true;
                 }
                }
               } 
              }

              const tree = new BinarySearchTree();
              tree.insert(9)
              tree.insert(4)
              tree.insert(6)
              tree.insert(20) 
              tree.insert(170)
              tree.insert(1)
              tree.remove(20)
              JSON.stringify(traverse(tree.root))

              //     9
             //  4     20
            // 1   6       170

            function traverse(node) {
              const tree = { value: node.value };
              tree.left = node.left === null ? null : traverse(node.left);
              tree.right = node.right === null ? null : traverse(node.right);
              return tree;
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition `currentNode.right.left === null` is set so that when it happens, the right node of the removed node `(20)` will take replace its position. Hence we have:

```
currentNode.right.left = currentNode.left;
```

When you remove node `(20)` using condition `currentNode.right.left === null`, the result will be the same as when using `currentNode.left === null` because both the conditions are satisfied in your case (both node `20` and node `6` doesn't have left children), leading to the same code being executed. You have to set up the test case in a way only one of the two conditions is satisfied in order to see the difference.

For example, if you create the tree using the code:

```
tree.insert(9)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(20) 
tree.insert(170)
tree.insert(30)
tree.insert(1)
```

You will have the following tree:

```
                     (9)
         (4                     20)
    (1          6)       (null      170)
(null null)(null null)(null null)(30 null)
```

When running the code `tree.remove(20)`, the condition `currentNode.right.left === null` won't be satisfied (node `170` has node `30` as left child) while your condition `currentNode.left === null` will (node `20` doesn't have left children).

Let consider condition `currentNode.right.left === null`. Since this condition is not satisfied, it will move to the `else` option (below `//Option 3: Right child that has a left child`), which is essentially get the leftmost node of node `20`'s right nodes to replace node `20`, in this case is node `30`, which will result in a new valid bts where every other nodes can be reached:

```
                     (9)
         (4                     30)
    (1          6)       (null      170)
(null null)(null null)(null null)(null null)
```

Let consider condition `currentNode.left === null`. Since this condition is satisfied, it will replace node `20` with the its right node, in this case is node `170`. Since node `17` has a left child (node `30`) and node `20` doesn't have a left child (`null`), when the code run through the line `currentNode.right.left = currentNode.left;`, node `170`'s left side will be set `null`, losing the reference to node `30`. The resulting bts will look something like:

```
                     (9)
         (4                     170)
    (1          6)       (null      null)
(null null)(null null)(null null)(30 null) <-- no way to reach node 30
```